# Typescript converting nested array into type

Tags: typescript, generics

This seems very basic but I'm not having any luck finding an answer.

I would like to call a function like this:

```
const result = myFunction({
  'keyA': [ 'arrayA1', 'arrayA2' ],
  'keyB': [ 'arrayB1', 'arrayB2' ],
});
```

I would like the result to be a key/value Record, where the keys are limited to `keyA` and `keyB`, and the value are also key/value records, with keys as `arrayA1`, `arrayA2`, etc:

```
result = {
  keyA: {
    arrayA1: 'example',
    arrayA2: 'example',
   },
   keyB: {
     arrayB1: 'example',
     arrayB2: 'example',
   }
 }
```

I'm struggling to come up with a generic function signature that will take the keys and array items in the parameter and turn them into the nested object keys.

```
function myFunction<
  T extends { [K in keyof T]: string[] },
  S extends keyof T,
  O extends T[K] // ???
  //O extends { InstanceType<T[K]> } // nope
  //O extends { [K in keyof T]: { [K2 in keyof T[K]]: K2 } } // very confused
>(structure: T): Record<S, Record<O, string>> { ... }
```

I can't seem to work out how to extract the nested string array, and convert it into a type specifying only those values as permitted strings.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs only two generic types:

```
function myFunction<
  T extends Record<string, S[]>,
  S extends string
>(structure: T): { 
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [K2 in T[K][number]]: string
    }
} { return null! }
```

`T` will hold the passed `structure` and is constrained to be an object with string keys where the values are `S`-arrays. `S` is constrained to be a `string`. We need `S` here to narrow down the type of the `string`s in the array to string literals.

The return type consists of two nested mapped types. The first one maps over the keys of `T` while the second one maps over the elements in `T[K]`.

```
const result = myFunction({
  'keyA': [ 'arrayA1', 'arrayA2' ],
  'keyB': [ 'arrayB1', 'arrayB2' ],
});

// const result: {
//     keyA: {
//         arrayA1: string;
//         arrayA2: string;
//     };
//     keyB: {
//         arrayB1: string;
//         arrayB2: string;
//     };
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDawLwwLYE8BiyYwUAluABQDeAUDDAOQDWCuAggwFwwDajAhnDj92ARgYAaAUJFsATAxgBdCXUYtcAIS69pwreKkNB%20zQuWqAvgEoA3DRoB6RzFCRYiFOm61n9fxpsPk4u-mEwJrKi3NBwpGAA5vZ%204f6R7HIxUHGJyaH%20lnnhGprBKakRMgZZOUkhFfTpZjXxdeX0hfWWDgBmRCTkYDgE-WTgADxqACowCAAeUAhgACYQMABKCKBwy%20OxrVIAyjxKAHyq9IezC0urMPuJNKcUscgkyIjcU9Y%20MGr0PAA0jB4jANCAejApkpgg0gXIQUMpkClDwwMhsAAjBBwJQw%207ZVr-GDdSwwKjwBBQD5DdGoVAAQhJQA)

Comment: Thank you!  I see now I was trying to construct the bulk of the type in the function parameters, but really I should've been trying to only break it down as little as needed in the parameters, and construct the bulk of it in the return type instead.